# Why does python confuse my packages for modules

Tags: python, import, absolute-path, relative-import

I have a project with 3 nested packages within the root package

```
clsgen 
-__init__.py
-main.py
-parsing
    -__init__.py
    - class1.py
    - class2.py
-generator
    -__init__.py
    -some_class_files
    -...
-utils
    -__init__.py
    -some_modules
    -...
```

Ive been having loads of difficulty (with python in general- probably the only thing Java/Eclipse does right in my opnion) when it comes to importing and using packages. Recently, I was able to skate by by using relative imports like `from .details import Details` to say: from a module in the current package/directory, called details, import the class  named "Details". I've added some new (potentially breaking) changes to the program, and now, the same relative import line above no longer works. It seems that the interpreter thinks that my packages are modules, and so, I cannot use absolute import instead.

for example, if I change the import to this:

```
from parsing.details import Details
```

I get this error:

```
>>> %Run class_dict.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\VsCode\python\classgenerator\parsing\class_dict.py", line 12, in <module>
    from parsing.details import Details
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\backend.py", line 305, in _custom_import
    module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parsing'
```

I've even tried overwriting the builtin **package** on a per-needs basis, like

```
__package__ = "parsing"
from parsing.details import Details
```

I'm pretty confident that I have my projects packaging structure set up correctly (like the first example above shows (but in more detail)). And I am also pretty confident I understand the concepts of packages, modules, relative vs absolute import. Yet this is a problem that haunts me whenever I try to make a multi package program with Python. I would really appreciate someone pointing out an error or suggesting what actions I can take to mitigate this persistent problem.

Comment: "It seems that the interpreter thinks that my packages are modules," packages are modules. A package is just a module that contains sub-modules. Those error messages will just refer to modules. Have you added the project root to your path? What is the working directory? It looks to me the correct absolute import is `clsgn.parsing.details`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga when you say 'have you added the project root to your path?' do you mean using the line ```sys.path.insert(0, "absolute path to my project directory")``` or the like before import statements? where is the best place to do this (seems a little cumbersome to do it whenever i need to import a class or module from within my project).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga also my working directory is ```C:\Users\Ben\VsCode\Python```, so for adding the project directory to my sys path, should i do ```C:\Users\Ben\VsCode\Python``` or ```C:\Users\Ben\VsCode\Python\clsgn```? thank you

Comment: Running from the command line (or equivalent from your IDE with the run config set up properly) should do it - how do you run those? What is this `%Run` ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D just invoking the file using the interpreter: ```C://path//to//python//interpreter C://path//to//current//file```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java imports are just syntactic sugar (no really). In python they are actual statements and they are resolved based on complex rules involving the sys.path variable and the current working directory. The correct way to run a python script (aka module) that resides in a package is:

```
$ C://path//to//python//interpreter.exe -m packagename.modulename
```

So in your case

```
$ cd "C:\Users\Ben\VsCode\python\"
$ C://path//to//python//interpreter.exe -m classgenerator.parsing.class_dict
```

This way the relative imports are resolved correctly as "C:\Users\Ben\VsCode\python" is automatically added to the sys.path and python scans it a finds the package classgenerator *and* the subpackage parsing